# g++: Disable the usage of segment register

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, memory-segmentation

I am working some binary code analysis and reverse engineering task on `x86 32-bit` `Ubuntu 14.04`. I am using `g++ 4.8.4` to compile the `C++` program.

I am wondering whether it is possible to prevent compiler from using segment registers. For example, `gs`.

An example of the usage is like below:

```
mov    %gs:0x8,%ebx
```

I am aware that some segment registers are used for stack canary checking. However, even if I have disabled such checking (`-fno-stack-protector`), still, there are quite a lot of usages for segment registers...

Comment: Do you have some example code? You could then try out a few permutations on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/).

Comment: If this is x86-32, it's also used for accessing thread local storage as part of the ELF ABI. I wrote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793556/addresses-of-thread-local-storage-variables/24795148#24795148) on TLS addressing.

Comment: What do you mean "quite a lot of usages"?  Are most of them the default segment register for the operation, and just being shown by the disassembler?  e.g. [`%es:(%edi)` for STOS?](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STOS:STOSB:STOSW:STOSD:STOSQ.html)?  If so, there aren't segment override prefixes in your code, it's just your disassembler being verbose.  Look at the compiler's asm output (`gcc -O3 -S`) instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output